# php if statement not working with or on stripos

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Probably something simple, but I can't find the same thing on SO...

I have an php file that creates an html email, and I need to check for two (or more) pieces of text in a string.

When I just do a normal `if`, it executes:

```
if (stripos($Q5Answer, '2')  !== false) {
  message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td> </td><td>". $Q5 ."</td>
</tr>"; 
}
```

But using an `OR` (using `"OR"` or `"||"`), it no longer displays

```
if (stripos($Q5Answer, '2') || stripos($Q5Answer, '1')  !== false) {
  message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td> </td><td>". $Q5 ."</td>
</tr>"; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if (stripos($Q5Answer, '2') !== false || stripos($Q5Answer, '1') !== false)

Also, take care using stripos function. Sometimes it can return values that are not false, but are evaluated as false. (Always use !== and === to avoid this situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add one more `!==false` there in your condition.Do like below:-

```
if (stripos($Q5Answer, '2') !== false || stripos($Q5Answer, '1') !== false) {
```

Comment: How do I do that again - is it by "upvoting" the answer?